# Activerecord database setup. Two tables or 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say we're designing a questionaire/survey to record answers for the populace of the USA. One way to setup a table is to have a question table with 4 columns, each representing a choice. A column on this table might be called choice1.

Another way to set this up is to have two tables, one questions table and one choices table and a question can have many choices. What is the benefit of this setup over just having one table?

Comment: for some questions you might have more or less than 4 choices, if you have separate table you can add as many choices as you want, while with single table you will have to add new columns.

Comment: https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire is a plugin that helps in quickly setting up a survey app. Check out their implementation for getting an idea of what issues should be handled while building such a system.

Comment: your first choice is not normalized and will lead to future headaches when the number of answers changes for a given question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is restrictive in that if you want to add questions to your survey you then also have to add a column. Your users will not be able to add questions without developer support (if you wanted that feature).

The second method, when supplemented by a join table gives you no such restriction, but all of your answers must be stored in the same column so you are limited by type, e.g. everything stored as string. You could, if needed, have an additional column in the question table defining the answer data type so your application knows how to cast the stored string.